# Updating an elements of an array in scala

Tags: scala

I need to update the elements of an array without creating a new array again

```
val funcRemoveQuotes=(x:String)=>
  {
    x.substring(1,x.length-1)

  }
probeFileLines.map(x => x._2.toString()).map(x => x.split(","))
.map(//.need to apply funcRemoveQuotes on each element of array)
```

I want to do it by way without using yield

Comment: I'm curious, what data elements, in `probeFileLines`, contain quote characters only _after_ calling `toString()` on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify an `Array`, in place, like so:

```
arr.indices.foreach(x => arr(x) = funcRemoveQuotes(arr(x)))
```